# data-scope="email" not returning email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a facebook connect website, and the facebook connect is returning everything i need except for the email, even though i have the data-scope saying i want the email.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
            '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>


<div id="social-register" class="registration_panel">
    <a id="facebook-login" class="fb_button fb_button_medium"  data-scope="email,user_checkins" href="home/login">
        <span class="fb_button_text">Login with Facebook</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what i could be doing wrong ? thx

Comment: where did you get the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the code you have in your question, I believe you are missing code to call to get user information.  After calling `FB.getLoginStatus(callBack)` and verifying they're logged in, then you can call `FB.api('/me?fields=email',callBack);`